# error getting classpath for JIRA

Tags: java, jira

I'm getting "error getting classpath for JIRA" while compiling a JIRA plugin.. what does it mean?  I'm attempting to compile a JIRA plugin using Galileo 3.3 + Maven2 + Atlassian Plugin SDK beta 6 on Ubutnu

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to pin down exactly what caused the classpath error, as you haven't provided contextual information. Perhaps you should start with [reading the plugin development guide](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DEVNET/Setting+up+your+Plugin+Development+Environment) from Atalassian?

Comment: Well I read that, and every other page from Atlassian, and googled, and varked.. Any other hints?  Cause I've tried all the things I can find on the Atlassian forums, on google, without any luck.. =(  I've been trying for about 5 weeks now

Comment: @loopywoof: So we're down to you providing more contextual information from the compiling operation ;)